# FFMPEG: How to apply and erosion filter on image

Tags: image, image-processing, filter, ffmpeg

I was wondering if there is a way in which I can apply an erosion filter to an image using ffmpeg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FFmpeg has an erosion filter.

For an image, the command template is

```
ffmpeg -i image -vf erosion -q:v 5 out.jpg
```

`q:v` is unrelated to the erosion filter and sets compression level of the JPEG output. Lower is better.

Comment: Specify output file extension as png.